# MySQL server has gone away ERROR

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: 
MySQL server has gone away in filename.php on line 201
```

query:

```
SELECT * FROM ta
    LEFT JOIN tb ON ta_id = tb_oid 
    LEFT JOIN tc ON ta_id = tc_oid 
    LEFT JOIN td ON ta_id = td_oid
WHERE 
    ta_time1 > 0 OR ta_time2 > 0 OR 
    tb_time1 > 0 OR tb_time2 > 0 OR 
    tc_time1 > 0 OR tc_time2 > 0 OR 
    td_time1 > 0 OR td_time2 > 0 
GROUP BY td_id 
ORDER BY  
    ta_time1 DESC, ta_time2 DESC,
    tb_time1 DESC, tb_time2 DESC,
    tc_time1 DESC, tc_time2 DESC,
    td_time1 DESC, td_time2 DESC
LIMIT 0, 40
```

How can i optimise this query?

Comment: Select * is a bad choice, at a minimum you are returning the joins fields twice and that is a waste of server and network resources. The fewer fields you return the better, so if you don't need every field from all tables (and since you have joins you don't), then specify the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set indexes on all fields, if you havn't done that already.
- Use as small fields as possibe. E.g. if the ID's are 128 byte strings where you can use a tiny int, use the latter

By the way, if you don't know what "has gone away" means, please check the manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html